# How to get rpy2 for QGIS on OSX?

Tags: python, qgis, r, osx

I am a new QGIS user, have installed QGIS on a Mac running Snow Leopard OSX 10.6.8 following all the instructions. QGIS seems to work well for everything other than when I boot up I get the message 
"Unable to load the plugin: Unable to load required package rpy2.
Please ensure that both R, and the corresponding version of Rpy2 are correctly installed".

I have installed Rpy2 several times and reloaded R. I have R version 2.15 loaded (but also RStudio).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How did you install rpy2? Did you use [pip](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2_download.html)?

Comment: What is the output if you start the Python interpreter and type in `from rpy2.robjects import robject` ? Do you get an error?

Comment: I installed rpy2 using the RPy2-2.2.4-1.dmg downloaded together with the other Python Modules required for QGIS.

Comment: When I enter from rpy2.robjects import robject in the Python terminal I get 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named rpy2.robjects
>>>

Answer (score 2):

A general installation will not work.  You need to install to your QGIS python folder (e.g. C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\ (root folder), C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages (modules)).